# Android - Append string for every request within a webview

Tags: android, webview

I'm working on a native app for GooglePlay, and have a FNG question. The app is a simple webview, and it works as expected, using this [tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/gettingstarted). However, I'd like to append every request from the app (webview) with a constant string, this way in the request logs I can determine which requests were from apps, and which were from the native website. It's easy enough to do for the landing page, but for subsequent actions such as log-in or create account, nothing is appended.

I was thinking I could create a class similar to the tutorial, where, for every link, I append the string. Being a FNG to android development I figured I'd better ask if there is a better way to accomplish the desired result before I start hacking away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the tutorial you mentioned has most of the answer you need.

I'm assuming that you want to append the string to the Url that is to be loaded into the webView. You can extend the WebViewClient class implementing
 [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading) Within this method you can use [loadUrl](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl) to load the webView with the passed Url with whatever modifications you want before returning true.

You need to call WebView.setWebViewClient to assign your WebViewClient to the WebView.